# Подскажите с чего начинать при создании программы "Планировщика задач" на C#?

Tags: c#

Начал писать программу Windows Forms на C# "Планирование рабочего времени" и не хватает знаний. Сам в C# не шарю, начинающий. Просьба указать как лучше начать,а точнее что нужно для этого, какие то библиотеки или службы..не знаю.
Программа, по моим мыслям должна состоять из: 1)авторизации пользователя; 2)локальной БД Access(пока что локальная и да-access); 3)и само собой интерфейс, чтобы можно было редактировать данные;

Comment: посмотри планировщик задач в XP или любой другой. а вообще начинающим такое делать не стоит.

Comment: С идеи. Сядь и потрать время, продумай, какова цель проекта, что он должен делать, как это должно выглядеть. Какие функции в нем нужны и нужны ли они. Когда ты поймешь, что тебе нужно в конечном итоге, тогда приступай к реализации. Надеюсь у тебя все получится :)

Comment: Вот стараюсь)Благодарю)

Comment: Вопрос интересный. Если напишишь библиотеку для этого то поделись. Я могу тоже что-нибудь туда добавить.

Comment: @codename0082016 возьмите Quartz.net, если нужна библиотека. Поучаствовать тоже можно, проект есть на github